# ways to send messages to a service?

Tags: c++, windows, service, udp, client-server

i had a client server program and i wanted to change the server to a service. so i took some code from here [Svp.cpp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). it works fine but i created the client server using UDP so i was wondering **is there another way to send messages to a service**? The client sends messages to the server(service) and the server just echoes them back. is it necessary to have a UDP or TCP connection to send and receive messages?

here is the part of the program that receives the messages from the client (the rest of the code is taken from Svp.cpp)

```
SOCKET socketS;

InitWinsock();
struct sockaddr_in local;
struct sockaddr_in from;
int fromlen = sizeof(from);
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_port = htons(1234);
local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

socketS = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
bind(socketS,(sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local));
while (1)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (recvfrom(socketS,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen)!=SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        sendto(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from, fromlen);
    }
}
closesocket(socketS);
```

Comment: Are the client and server apps on the same machine?

Comment: yes they are on the same machine

Comment: You don't really check for errors. Try the same in a normal program, but also check for errors and print them out in case there is an error.

Comment: The only difference between a service and a "normal" program is that the OS is starting the service, everything else is just equal.

Comment: i know the program is not complete yet but it does work. i want to know is a UDP connection needed here?

Comment: So the question is really: How to best do [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocess_communication)?

Comment: yes i guess that's right

Answer (score 0):

If the client and server applications are on the same machine, you could use Named Pipes instead.

[Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I had a system service that I had to remove the UI, and instead of creating a socket to communicate between the UI and the service, we used Named Pipes. This was nice, because some of our clients were worried about security with an open listening TCP socket on the machine.

If you go this route, you have to set up some sort of signaling between the two applications, because the pipes do not notify you of reads/writes like sockets do. But it is a very workable solution.

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure how using named pipes can send messages

Comment: From the link I gave you: "A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients." That is what a named pipe is for - sending messages between two different pieces of software.

Comment: From a link on the previous page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365799(v=vs.85).aspx - this gives instructions on how to use them.